# How do you handle Localization/i18N in notifications?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, internationalization

First of all thank you for your time reading and maybe answering this question.

We have a react native app that uses react native Localize to handle i18n, and Firebase to handle notifications, those are sended in a PHP server.

We save the user´s locale (which we take from the phone) in our database after sign up. When we send the notification we translate it according to the users locale before sending it to the app.

But the user has the ability to change his phone language, so the notification might arrive in a different language because he has change it.

We first tought of checking each time the user loads the app if it´s locale has changed and update the bbdd field.

But we are not sure if this is a right approach.

How do you usually manage it?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I believe that other solution is offer the language setting inside your own app instead depend of operating system language, already see others apps making it.

With the language config inside your app, can you have total control of language to send push notification if you persists it in your backend.